# How do I query many-to-many relationship in NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

For instance, in [this example](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/08/nhibernate-many-to-many-relationships/) Employee and Address has a many-to-many relationship, and an `Employee` class has a property

```
public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

In this example, how would I create a linq query to get all Employee that has `X` as one of its address (X is a `Address` variable)?

I can think of:

```
q => q.Where(employee => employee.Addresses.IndexOf(X)>=0);
```

But I think this will not be optimised and will be very costly.

Comment: I guess you don't prefer to create an 'EmployeeAddresses' view and query against it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
q => q.Where(e => e.Addresses.Any(<your condition goes here>))
```

for example

```
q => q.Where(e => e.Addresses.Any(a => a.City == "Moscow"))
```